# Flutter logging text cut when debugging for Web

Tags: flutter-web

I use flutter logging.

When logging

```
static final Logger log = new Logger('XXX');
log.info("This is a longer text to display in the console which will be truncated and I do not know why.");
```

I only get

```
[INFO   ] 21:08:20 - XXX - This is a l…ole which will be truncated and I do not know why.
```

in the console when using flutter for web... while debugging for Android shows everything as expected.

What am I doing wrong?